# Toggle price on category/view.phtml and product/view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, price, view.phtml

I need an option to toggle off/on the price **(category/view.phtml and product/view.phtml)**.

Let's say a logged in customer wants to hide the price.

So he ticks a checkbox or anything like that which hides prices on the both mentioned **view.phtml**

Is there any way to achieve something like that in magento 1.9.3.6 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Create the button to click
- Whenever the button is clicked.  Create and set a session variable
  that the price will not show like:

> Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setMyValue("nopriceview");

- Have a check in the (category/view.phtml and product/view.phtml)
  where if the session is active:

> if (Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getNoPriceView())

then add a container around the price and add inline css display none.

For example:

You have the hide price button inside a form.

```
<form name="priceView" action="" method="post" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="priceCheck" />
</form>
```

Then you also have PHP code to check if the form has been submitted.

```
<?php
    if(!(isset($_SESSION["priceView"]))) {
        $_SESSION["priceView"] = "yesPrice";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['priceCheck'])){
        if($_SESSION["priceView"] == "yesPrice") {
            $_SESSION["priceView"] = "noPrice";
        } elseif($_SESSION["priceView"] == "noPrice") {
            $_SESSION["priceView"] = "yesPrice";
        }
    }
?>
```

I'm using basic PHP but if you need this the Magento way we can do that also.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. Just for my understanding: I have to put the session


Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setMyValue("nopriceview");


into a button like jQuery toggle()  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

If yes, how would I do that?

Comment: Create a form where you will submit the button data to add a session variable or create a button where it will ajax a session variable.  Then have the form or ajax have a check if the session is active or not to turn it on or off.

Comment: I'm very sorry for being so stupid. I got the Magento part but I struggle with the button thing. Is there any stackexchange or example I could use? Or could you point me in the right direction if you don't mind? Thank you very much.

Comment: @zlep I better just edit my answer and elaborate.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it with your basic PHP code but it did not work unfortunately. I guess it has to be the Magento way to work correctly? Which is kind of more difficult than I thought.